# Getting specific data from a website with python

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://covid19.saglik.gov.tr/"
R=requests.get(url)             
print(R.text)
```

Question:  Hello friends,I must receive below specific values from  above website. These values are changing daily.When the program runs, it should be able to print out the specified key from the website .For example: print(data["tarih"]) ,  print(data["gunluk_test"]) ,  print(data["gunluk_vaka"]  etc. in html script. How can I do that ?

CODE's OUTPUT RESULT:

var sondurumjson = [{"tarih":"13.05.2021","gunluk_test":"201.295","gunluk_vaka":"11.534","gunluk_hasta":"1.217","gunluk_vefat":"238","gunluk_iyilesen":"55.472","toplam_test":"50.259.943","toplam_hasta":"5.083.996","toplam_vefat":"44.059","toplam_iyilesen":"4.856.763","toplam_yogun_bakim":"","toplam_entube":"","hastalarda_zaturre_oran":"4,0","agir_hasta_sayisi":"2.765","yatak_doluluk_orani":"43,7","eriskin_yogun_bakim_doluluk_orani":"65,0","ventilator_doluluk_orani":"32,4","ortalama_filyasyon_suresi":"","ortalama_temasli_tespit_suresi":"8","filyasyon_orani":"99,9"}];//]]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import json

url="https://covid19.saglik.gov.tr/"

R=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(R.content,"html.parser" )

script=soup.find_all("script")[18]

s=str(script).split('\nvar sondurumjson = ')

#print(s[1])

a=str(s[1])

b=a.split("\r")

#print(b[0])

c=b[0].partition(';')

data=c[0]
#print(data)

data = json.loads(data)

print( "Tarih:", data[0]['tarih'])

print("Günlük Test:", data[0]['gunluk_test'])

print( "Günlük Vaka:", data[0]['gunluk_vaka'])

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dict is already recognised by python so json.loads fails did you paste the output of the api or did you print the dict that you are working on?
Anyhow if that is the result of your api you can just do this to access everything in the dictionary:

```
sondurumjson = [{"tarih":"13.05.2021","gunluk_test":"201.295","gunluk_vaka":"11.534","gunluk_hasta":"1.217","gunluk_vefat":"238","gunluk_iyilesen":"55.472","toplam_test":"50.259.943","toplam_hasta":"5.083.996","toplam_vefat":"44.059","toplam_iyilesen":"4.856.763","toplam_yogun_bakim":"","toplam_entube":"","hastalarda_zaturre_oran":"4,0","agir_hasta_sayisi":"2.765","yatak_doluluk_orani":"43,7","eriskin_yogun_bakim_doluluk_orani":"65,0","ventilator_doluluk_orani":"32,4","ortalama_filyasyon_suresi":"","ortalama_temasli_tespit_suresi":"8","filyasyon_orani":"99,9"}]
new_object = sondurumjson[0]

print(new_object['tarih'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **R.json()** instead of **R.text**